# How to write #pragma openmp in multiple lines?

Tags: c, openmp, pragma

I have a long list of variable for private and share. How do I write in multiple lines? I am repeating the question here, just because stackoverflow wouldn't let me submit the question otherwise.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Pragmas are interpreted by the compiler after preprocessing, so you can just use the normal line-continuation mechanism:

```
#pragma omp parallel
```

can become:

```
#pragma \
omp \
parallel
```